# How to deal with Google-Coral source code, especially libedgetpu library?

Tags: google-coral, tflite, edge-tpu

I'm dealing with the project using Coral-dev board, and now I need to find out how the libedgetpu and dev-board communicates.

I tried to study with source code of libedgetpu, but as there are many files and most codes are inherited, so I can't find where the exact code is executed.

What I really want to know is how the board recognize the tpu and the process of how sensors are transmitted to tpu.

Whether it's using a different API or calling a system call, I want to see and check the source code myself.